# Array Objects "duplicating"

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I am creating a game in java. I am using an array of Armor's for equipment
The issue, is that whenever I change 1 variable in my array, the other objects are also affected. This looks like a pointer issue but, all of the objects have been initialized as separate and called as new.

```
private Armor[] equip = new Armor[3];
public Inventory()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<3;i++)
        equip[i] = new Armor();

    equip[0] = new Armor("head","You don't have head equipment","head",0,10,0,0);
    equip[1] = new Armor("tunic","A simple farmers tunic","chest",0,10,0,0);
    equip[2] = new Armor("baggy pants","Basic pants woven from rough cloth","legs",0,10,0,0);


    System.out.println(armorDes(0));
    System.out.println(armorDes(1));
    System.out.println(armorDes(2));
}
```

All of the print lines output

```
baggy pants
0 armor
10 evasion bonus
Basic pants woven from rough cloth
```

instead of their own stats.

This was tested with a debugger and all of the objects are declared to different locations in data. Is this a java issue are am I just stupid?

Comment: Sounds like you might have declared all the fields of `Armor` `static` or something, but with only this code to look at, we can't really tell what's going on.

Comment: Welp looks like I'm stupid then :D  error resolved

Answer (score 0):

Code is unclear above

```
private Armor[] equip = new Armor[3];
public Inventory()
{
for(int i = 0; i<3;i++)
    equip[i] = new Armor();// Why creating object using default constructor here? no use

equip[0] = new Armor("head","You don't have head equipment","head",0,10,0,0);
equip[1] = new Armor("tunic","A simple farmers tunic","chest",0,10,0,0);
equip[2] = new Armor("baggy pants","Basic pants woven from rough cloth","legs",0,10,0,0);

// Use toString() method in Armour class to see the values present in variables. 
//Also be sure all variables are instance variables 

System.out.println(equip[0]);
System.out.println(equip[1]);
System.out.println(equip[2]);

//System.out.println(armorDes(0));
//System.out.println(armorDes(1));
//System.out.println(armorDes(2));
```

}